# print part of a timestamp using python

Tags: python, timestamp

I am outputting timestamps (eg. 2012-02-24 13:18:45.552882) and I'd like to remove the last part (here would be .552882) from the output file, so I would only have date and time to the second. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your timestamp stored -- string? `datetime.time`? `time.time`?

Comment: I'm using datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp() . I tried using time.ctime() and I got it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) method in `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime.strftime(format)`. See [this](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> date = '2012-02-24 13:18:45.552882'
>>> good, bad = date.split('.')
>>> good
'2012-02-24 13:18:45'
>>> bad
'552882'
```

Comment: Not the best way: there's already a utility to handle parsing and formatting timestamps so you don't have to write manual string splitting code yourself.